# Multiple regression - High adjusted R^2 but the residuals are high

Tags: r, r-squared, leverage

I used the multiple regression models to derive the outcomes after using AIC pairwise comparison and deleted the outliers, high leverage points.

And it seems good, the adjusted R^2 acheived 0.9543, see below:

```
Call:
lm(formula = P ~ V + EF + W + H, data = PS)

Residuals:
Min      1Q     Median      3Q     Max 
-22.448 -14.576   2.949  12.524  26.034 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -2.186e+03  5.209e+02  -4.196 0.000201 ***
V           1.511e-01  1.033e-02  14.633 9.96e-16 ***
EF           1.183e+01  3.239e+00   3.653 0.000917 ***
W           -1.135e+00  4.205e-01  -2.698 0.011028 *  
H            3.192e+01  8.482e+00   3.763 0.000678 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 15.79 on 32 degrees of freedom
(13 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.9593, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9543 
F-statistic: 188.8 on 4 and 32 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

However, when I was inspecting the residuals, they are fairly high.
With the R^2 higher than 0.95. I expect the residuals should be around 5% but actually not. It's kind of weird. See below for the (actual - fitted)/actual.

```
tidy((PS$P-fitted(fita2))/PS$P)
         x
1   0.01778472
2  -0.19525412
3  -0.01824948
4  -0.24418585
5  -0.06475068
6   0.65211477
7   0.58158990
8  -0.14876657
9  -0.27050744
10  0.15220738
11  0.14239352
12  0.02274694
13  0.10920921
14  0.04696290
15 -0.07793881
16 -0.32173830
17 -0.60332883
18 -1.47499192
19 -0.70576325
20 -0.04088402
21 -1.11266825
22 -1.13704286
23 -0.72987082
24 -0.50573858
25  0.38938329
26  0.57790490
27  0.21233140
28 -0.42890622
29  0.27630390
```

Plot of Residuals vs Fitted:

[image]

Normal Q-Q plot:

[image]

Comment: Could you please add the output of `plot(fita2, which = 1)` to your question?

Comment: @Roland, kindly see the plots attached, thanks 1. Residuals VS Fitted
http://postimg.org/image/6b921nqdf/ 2. Normal Q-Q
http://postimg.org/image/4srg1wnyb/

Comment: Based on what formula would you expect the relative residuals to be around 5%?

Comment: I assumed it based on the ajusted R^2.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a clear basis for your assessment that the residuals are "fairly high."  Certainly "high" is in the eye of the beholder and is context-dependent, but in most non-physics contexts an R-square of 95% indicates a very accurate model.  If you changed the y-axis of your "Residuals vs Fitted" graph to match the x-axis, the residuals would show up as very small indeed.

It should help if you keep several quantities distinct:

1. The residual, (observed - fitted)
2. The standardized residual, (residual/[standard deviation of residuals])
3. Your (idiosyncratic?) metric, the residual as a % of the
   observed value:  (residual/observed).

Each of these has its own scale and needs to have its magnitude judged accordingly.  I don't see a mean of 5% as a standard or reliable benchmark to judge the "goodness" of any of the 3.

R-squared itself does not relate directly to any of the 3;  it's an indicator of the regression sum of squares in relation to (divided by) the residual sum of squares.

Some other notes:  4 decimal places is excessive precision to report when your df is only 32.  Also, your Normal Q-Q plot does indicate something potentially "off" about this regression, but it concerns not the mean size of the (standardized) residuals but rather the way they are distributed at the tails.  This regression produces a few more that are relatively extreme than would be ideal.  This really shows up just as well in the "Residuals vs Fitted" graph, where fitted values at the low and high end are paired with some particularly high residuals.  The bottom line is that this model seems to predict substantially better for some types of cases (those with fitted values between 140 and 320) than for others.

Comment: Would you mind taking a closer look at the QQ plot?  To me it looks like the residual distribution has much *shorter* than Normal tails (which isn't problematic) rather than a "few more that are relatively extreme."  And could you explain what  aspect of the output suggests prediction may be "substantially better" for fitted values in [140,320]?  I cannot find any significant evidence of that.  A close reading of the question suggests that a confusion between $R^2$ and relative error may lie at its heart: perhaps addressing that would be most helpful of all.

Comment: Please go ahead and answer with a better account of the Q-Q plot and/or an expanded treatment of the "5%" idea.  As far as [140,320], I see the mean absolute error as about half as large there (~8) as elsewhere (~15).

Comment: That would be an illusion brought about by the sparseness of the data there.